# Can we please reopen this question about NuSpock?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

This question was originally closed as "Not Constructive", reopened, then closed again as "Opinion-based".

**[Did Spock warn of disasters in the new Star Trek universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23283/did-spock-warn-of-disasters-in-the-new-star-trek-universe)**

Given that it's unlikely that we'll see OldSpock in any future films, I've edited the question to reflect that any answers can be addressed to the three 'reboot' films (as well as any comics/additional materials that have been spawned alongside).

**Can we please now reopen it?**

Comment: Now that you ask so nicely :)

Comment: It's now been reopened by the community.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - And has attracted a close vote :-)

Comment: @Valorum Since then it's already [passed through the review queue](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/close/103993) again with a unanimous "Leave Open" decision.